# How can I get Input from a paragraph in Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="amount_due" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{trans('sale.amount_due')}}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
          <p class="form-control-static">Paragraph I want to input</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

From above paragraph class I want text in my controller. In this paragraph the due amount shows via angular js. And I just want to get that value to add in database

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`<textarea>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) with the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
   <textarea rows=10 cols=40 ng-model="paragraph"></textarea>
   <p>{{paragraph}}</p>
</div>
```